# Can you extend a generic class that takes a List of parameters?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that I want to extend with x number of classes, but I only want to extend it once. More specifically:

```
// Project Beans

public class User implements MarkerInterface
public class Tree implements MarkerInterface
public class Dog implements MarkerInterface
... more classes in the future ..

// Generic Class

public class GenericsImpl<Collection<T extends MarkerInterface>> {
    for(T t : list){
    ... implementation .. 
    }
}

// Class Extension

public class Service extends GenericsImpl<User, Tree, Dog, ... n> {
... service implementation ..
}
```

Is this scenario possible? I'd like to be able to extend the generic class with any number of classes that implement the marker interface I have defined.

Comment: Why not just GenericsImpl<MarkerInterface> ?    Hardcoding all the subtypes is bad practice - if you add a new type next year, you'll have to remember to modify this code as well.

Comment: Can't do `GenericsImpl`, because you can't write code (i.e. `for` loop) directly in a class. It has to be in a method.

Comment: No it's not possible. But it sounds like something like the [*visitor pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example) might help you.